# how to create a negative lookbehind expression that - added - must not be an empty word

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I want to find elements matching namespaces/class contexts in C++ which aren't `std` or global scope

I'm using this:

```
>>> re.findall("(?<!std)::(\w+)","my_namespace::my_function std::vector ::open i=0;::open")
['my_function', 'open', 'open']
```

so `vector` is filtered out as I expected, but global scoped `open` is also extracted (I need a non-empty word before `::` that isn't `std`, and `;` doesn't qualify)

I know I can extract namespace and name and post process like this:

```
>>> [b for a,b in re.findall("(\w+)::(\w+)","my_namespace::my_function std::vector ::open i=0;::open") if a != 'std']
['my_function']
```

but is there a pure regex way to do this ?

Comment: Basically you just want to check if there's a word character in front of the `::`, right? Like `(?<!std)(?<=\w)::(\w+)`?

Comment: yes, a word, but not `std`

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\b(?!std::)\w+::(\w+)', s)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1z1fK/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add another lookbehind assertion:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<!std)(?<=\w)::(\w+)", "my_namespace::my_function std::vector ::open")
['my_function']
```

- `(?<=\w)` checks if `::` is preceded by a word character

Comment: yes, that can happen. `i = 0;::open("foo");` is valid

Comment: Hmm in that case `r"(?<!std)(?<=\w)::(\w+)"` might be better

Comment: That's fine. I also suggest `\b::(?<!std..)(\w+)` with one fewer lookbehind.

Comment: Yes that's shorter but it was on purpose.

Comment: `r"\b(?<!\bstd)::(\w+)"` might be more accurate actually.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a regex solution like

```
re.findall(r'\b(?!std::)\w+::(\w+)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1z1fK/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!std::)` - no `std::` immediately to the right of the current location is allowed
- `\w+::` - 1+ word chars and `::`
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (the actual output of `re.findall`): 1+ word chars.